# Recursion in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have a function like this:

```
function test($T0){
  $T01 = $T0-$T0/2;
  $T02 = $T0+$T0/2;
  if($T01<$T0){
    test($T01);
  } else if($T02<$T0){
    test($T02);
  } else {}
  $result = array($T01,$T02);
    return $result;
  }

  $T0 = 50;
  $result = test($T0);
  echo $result[0];
```

Why this function is not recursion?

Comment: This line else {} won't help much. It should be else {

Comment: Your function is recursive.  What are you getting and what are you expecting that makes you think that it is not?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624313/9473764

Answer (score 2):

> *To understand recursion you must understand recursion*

You forget to return values in your ifs.

Proper code:

```
<?php
 function test($T0){
   $T01 = $T0-$T0/2;
   $T02 = $T0+$T0/2;
   if($T01 < $T0) return test($T01);
   else if($T02 < $T0) return test($T02);
   else return array($T01,$T02);
 }

 $T0 = 50;
 $result = test($T0);
 echo $result[0];
 ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Always remember to check every condition that may appear. Don't do else {} cause it can make infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `return` on your recursive calls:

```
return test($T01);
```

and

```
return test($T02);
```

In addition, you seem to have strange placement of braces on your `else` clause.  Most likely it should be:

```
else {
    $result = array($T01,$T02);
    return $result;
}
```

Finally, it's worth noting that this function will (theoretically) cause your code to recurse indefinitely, as you're just dividing a positive number in 2 all the time until it reaches 0.  In theory this never happens.  In practice, you'll recurse to some very-very small number at which the difference with 0 will be below the floating point precision.  In my test this number was `4.9406564584125E-324` (i.e. about 0.0....0494 with ... being 322 zeros).

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing return at the end of your function call, so it is going into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

As I debug the code:

> In your first condition the `$T01` will become the zero each time. And
>   then it will reach in first condition and call to again to function
>   and you are passing the zero value that time. So the value of $T01 and
>   $T02 becomes zero in second time and it will go in else condition. So
>   This function will not recursion no more again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is recursive only but the value of t01 is always less than t02, so its going into an infinite loop